# Update the value of text box with respect to expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to update the value of a textbox with respect to expression in angularjs check this code

```
<td><input type="text" ng-model="entry.sale_qty" required  style="width: 200px" ></td>
<td><input type="text" ng-model="entry.sale_price" required  style="width: 200px"></td>
<td><span> <input type="number" ng-model="entry.sale_amount" required>
          {{entry.sale_price*entry.sale_qty|number}}
</span> </td>`
```

The value  generated by expression should get populated to the third text-box ??

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign it to another scope variable

```
<input type="number" ng-model="entry.sale_amount = entry.sale_qty * entry.sale_price" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your html

```
<div ng-controller="testController">

<td><input type="text" ng-model="entry.sale_qty" required  style="width: 200px" ng-change="updateVal(entry.sale_qty)"></td>

<td><input type="text" ng-model="entry.sale_price" required  style="width: 200px" ng-change="updateVal2(entry.sale_price)" ></td>

<td><span> <input type="number" ng-model="entry.sale_amount" required>
      {{entry.sale_amount}}
</span> </td>

</div>
```

and in your controller

```
function testController($scope) {
$scope.entry={
    sale_qty:'',
    sale_price:'',
    sale_amount:''
};

$scope.updateVal = function(val) {
 $scope.entry.sale_amount=val*$scope.entry.sale_price;
};

$scope.updateVal2 = function(val) {
 $scope.entry.sale_amount=val*$scope.entry.sale_qty;
};

}
```